# Error when Dynamically Resizing iFrame using iframe-resizer

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, iframe-resizer

I am trying to dynamically resize the height of an iFrame using "[iframe-resizer](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer)" However this is not working as expected.

I have added this code to my display HTML document

```
<script src="js/iframeResizer.min.js"></script>
<iframe id="myIframe" src="l3-main.html"></iframe>
<script>
   iFrameResize({ log: true }, '#myIframe')
</script>
```

and this code to my iframe content HTML document

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js"></script>
```

as well as this in my css file

```
iframe {
    width: 1px;
    min-width: 100%;
    border: none;
}
```

However, I am getting this error when viewing the page in the Console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: iFrameResize is not defined

Searching though stackoverflow and other resources I have not yet been able to find a solutions, thanks in advance to anyone who has sugestions.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you dont have install min.js code. You use code like code in documentation, but  you dont use a `<style>` with 1px width and min width 100%.

Comment: I do have the following style code in my css file

iframe {
    width: 1px;
    min-width: 100%;
    border: none;
}

Comment: i have not idea

Answer (score 0):

The code in the question is correct. I would check that the JS file is loading ok.